# Finding multiple substring inside of a string

Tags: c++

So, I want to output a piece of code that's inside of some [], but the problema is: It only shows the first ocurrent, the second and so on isn't showed.

Already tried do use vector in order to do that but it didn't suceed.

```cpp
std::string get_line(std::string s, std::string start_delim,
        std::string stop_delim)
{
    unsigned first_delim_pos = s.find(start_delim);
    unsigned end_pos_of_first_delim = first_delim_pos + start_delim.length();
    unsigned last_delim_pos = s.find(stop_delim);

    return s.substr(end_pos_of_first_delim,
            last_delim_pos - end_pos_of_first_delim);
}

int main()
{
    string word = "[this] is a [test]";
    std::vector<std::string> list;

    for (int i= 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        std::string start_line = "[";
        std::string stop_line = "]";
        std::string l_line_ = get_line(word, start_line, stop_line);

        list.push_back(l_line_);

        cout << " The word is: " << list[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

So as I said, I expected the output to be:

```
The word is: this
The word is: text
```

But what is shown is:

```
The word is: this
The word is: this
```

Comment: You're always looking for the first start delim position and the first end delim position. Store somehow your previous result and pass it as second argument to `s.find`, it will be looking for delims after your previous result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a function that returns vector of strings where remember last end position and continue from it:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_words( const std::string &text, 
                                    const std::string &b,
                                    const std::string &e )
{
    std::vector<std::string> r;
    std::string::size_type epos = 0;
    while( true ) {
        auto bpos = text.find( b, epos );
        if( bpos == std::string::npos ) break;
        bpos += b.length();
        epos = text.find( e, bpos );
        if( epos == std::string::npos ) break;
        r.push_back( text.substr( bpos, epos - bpos ) );
        epos += e.length();
    }
    return r;
}
```

your current function as written has no way to continue from where it stopped before.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/0WkR9S)